# Elasticsearch query words spread across multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to make a query in Elasticsearch which returns documents **only if all of the words** from a search text are found not matter in which field. For example:

```
searchText = "term1 term2 term3 term4"
fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6']
```

If all words from searchText are in any field from 1 to 6, then return the documents. Else return nothing. Thanks!

This kind of document should be returned:

```
searchText = 'We need to change ourselves'
fields = [
  field1: "We are happy.",
  field2: "change ourselves",
  field3: "You are the one I need"
  field4: "to be",
  field5: "irrelevant",
  field6: ""
]
```

but not this one (not found: `We`, `ourserves`):

```
searchText = 'We need to change ourselves'
fields = [
  field1: "I am happy.",
  field2: "change",
  field3: "You are the one I need"
  field4: "to be",
  field5: "irrelevant",
  field6: "something"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#query-dsl-multi-match-query) with AND operator

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "term1 term2 term3 term4",
      "fields": [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        "field4",
        "field5",
        "field5"
      ],
      "operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

As already answered by @Razvan Theodor, [cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) will enable search of query words spread across multiple fields

Modified query will be

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "term1 term2 term3 term4",
      "fields": [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        "field4",
        "field5",
        "field5"
      ],
      "operator": "AND",
      "type": "cross_fields" // note this
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `operator: "and"` and `type: "cross_fields"` will do the magic :) Why don't you update your answer inserting `type: "cross_fields"`?

Comment: I'll upvote and accept it as accurate if you put `type: "cross_fields"` in :)

Comment: What if I need to query only parts of words? Let's say something like this: `Mich Jack` should return documents like: `{ "first_name": "Jackson", "last_name": "Michael"}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
       "query": "term1 term2 term3 term4",
       "type": "cross_fields",
       "operator": "and",
       "fields" => {
            "field1",
            "field2",
            "field3",
            "field4",
            "field5",
            "field6"
        }
    }
}
```